# Как измененить объект формы из другого класса

Tags: c#, winforms, события

Нужно изменять значение textbox из другого класса, но никак не могу это сделать. Поискав в гугле понял, что это можно сделать с помощью событий или изменив модификатор доступа textbox в свойствах на public, а затем создав в классе объект формы и через него изменять значение textbox, что у меня не вышло. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

Вариант 1:

```
 public class ClientObject
{
    public delegate void MethodChatLog(string message);
    public event MethodChatLog writeInChatLog;

    ...

    public void Process()
    {

        Form1 form1 = new Form1();

        try
        {
            Stream = client.GetStream();

            // Получаем имя пользователя
            userName = GetMessage();
            string message = userName + " вошел в чат.";
            // Рассылаем сообщение о входе в чат всем подключенным пользователям
            server.BroadcastMessage(message, Id);
            writeInChatLog(message);
  ...
```

---

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    ClientObject clientObject = new ClientObject();

    static ServerObject server;
    static Thread listenerThread;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
            server = new ServerObject();
            listenerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(server.Listen));
            listenerThread.Start(); // старт потока
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            server.Disconnect();
        }

        clientObject.writeInChatLog += MessageChatLog;
    }

    public void MessageChatLog(string message)
    {
        chatLogTB.Text += message + "\r\n";
    }
}
```

Вариант 2:

```
...
public void Process()
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();

        try
        {
            Stream = client.GetStream();

            // Получаем имя пользователя
            userName = GetMessage();

            string message = userName + " вошел в чат.";
            server.BroadcastMessage(message, Id);
            form1.chatLogTB.Text += message; // ничего не изменяет
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Самый правильный вариант- это события, так как благодаря этому механизму компоненты становятся слабосвязанными.

Да и с логической точки- это смотрится более правильно: Хочешь менять данные в зависимости от другого окна? Подпишись на события.

Все, что нужно - это создать в одном из классов событие, а в другом классе на него подписаться.

Answer (score 0):

Все довольно просто:

Передавай из одной формы в другую this. То есть инстанс даной формы.

И сделай или пабликом нужный элемент или создай паблик функцию/параметр который делает нужное действие. Таким макаром ты будешь иметь доступ из вызываемой формы доступ к нужному элементы вызывающей формы.

Если же нужно наоборот -- из вызывающей формы получить доступ к элементу вызываемой -- даже передавать ничего не нужно. В вызывающей формы и так есть инстанс вызываемой. Подход тот же, в принципе, просто без передачи this :)